# Password authentication in Django returning false

Tags: python, django

Jwt broken, tried to do it manually but it keeps returning false

```
In [2]: me = User.objects.all()[1]

In [3]: me.password
Out[3]: 'password'

In [4]: me.username
Out[4]: 'cchilders'

In [5]: me.email
Out[5]: 'cchilders'

In [9]: me.check_password('password')
Out[9]: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password should be hashed, call set_password

```
me.set_password(‘password’)
me.check_password(‘password’)
```